# Android Layout help

Tags: android, image, layout

I am writing a program that should have the following layout:

[image]

I've tried this so far:

1. Make entire Layout a LinearLayout
2. Map is in a Frame Layout
3. Picture from camera is in a Frame Layout
4. The rest are in a Relative Layout

Everything works from 1-3 but the edittext boxes dont appear at all.

Does someone have a better way for me to organize the layouts in order to achieve the above image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
    <MapView android:width="0dp" android:height="100dp" android:weight="1"/>
    <ImageView android:width="0dp" android:height="100dp" android:weight="1"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  <EditText/>
  <EditText/>
  <EditText/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is the appropriate way to do it.

Comment: that's surely the more elegant approach ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about `TableLayout`?
In the first `TableRow` the map and the camera picture, both with `weight=1`
In row two, three and four one `EditText` each

a TableLayout xml like that (I used `ImageView`s instead of map and camera picture for demonstration)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:padding="10dip">
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_weight="1" android:padding="10dip"></ImageView>
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_weight="1" android:padding="10dip"></ImageView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:gravity="center|center_horizontal" android:layout_weight="1" android:padding="10dip"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="center" android:padding="10dip"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow4" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:gravity="center" android:layout_weight="1" android:padding="10dip"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

would turn out to look like:

[image]

Comment: The thing is how can i limit the size of the mapview? You cant seem to do anything else other than fill_parent for height and width otherwise it crashes so that's why i put it in a frameLayout with a custom size

Comment: TableLayouts are too complicated :)

Comment: in your solution you don't really need LL

Comment: yep, that's absolutely right - I just forgot to clean the default layout up before I inserted the Table.. anyway, your solution is definitely the one to go here